# Generalizing the conditions after splitting of a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Consider I have a cron expression as "* * */2 * *" I have to extract the recurrence on days ,hours and minutes if it is not "*" . 
I have the below function which works as well.

```
public void CronDivision(string cron)
{
string days, value;
 string[] cronDiv = cron.split(' ');
 if(cronDiv[2] != "*")
 {
  days = "Days"
  value = cronDiv[2].split('/')[1];
 }
 else if(cron[1] != "*)
 {
  //Similar logic
 }
 else if(cron[0] != "*)
 {
  //Similar logic
 }
 else if(cron[3] != "*)
 {
  //different logic for extracting weeks
 }
else if(cron[4] != "*)
 {
  //different logic for extracting years
 }
}
```

How do I generalize the above function so that I dont want to use many if else/switch statements with hardcoded numbers like1,2,3 and so on after the division of cron expression.

Can it be made more readable without the obvious solution of splitting the actual cron expression and extracting it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this if-elseif construct, rather than if-if. You could have run into situations where expression could have values for more than one part. say "40 9 * * 1"

Comment: @anu : considering the cron is right( I have customized where only either hours or minutes or days exist), I am interested in refactoring after division and extraction .I am concerned about the readability to improvise the code so as to remove  hardcoded values as 0 th part,1st part etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments that you do not expect more than one condition to happen, you can avoid explicit indices by using Enum. The If/Switch cases can be replaced with a dictionary, which maps indices(or better Enum) to Actions(that needs to be performed for each case).

For example,

```
var cron =  "* * */2 * ";
var arr = cron.Split(new[]{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var value = arr.Select((x,index)=>new {Value=x, Index=index}).First(x=>!x.Value.Equals("*"));
var dictionaryOfActions = new Dictionary<Position,Action>
{
    [Position.Minute] = ()=> ProcessMinute(),
    [Position.Hour] = ()=> ProcessHour(),
    [Position.Day] = ()=> ProcessDay(),
};
dictionaryOfActions[(Position)value.Index]();
```

Where Position is defined as

```
public enum Position
{
    Minute,
    Hour,
    Day 
}
```

and ProcessMinute,ProcessHour etc represents actions that needs to be performed on each conditions.